# How to filter and show Name and address in edittext field in same activity on selection of Roll Number?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I have an Activity School Class created.

- Spinner Roll Number is having list of roll number from table SchoolClass (SQLITEDB).
- There is EDITTEXT - Name
- There is EDITTEXT - Address

I want when I select Roll Number -01 from drop down it should check in database for Name and Address where Roll Number is 01 and show Name and Address in Respective Edittext fields. and so on for other Roll Numbers

**NOTE:** I do not want any button to press for search it should be dynamic on selection based like textwatcher or other solution. Kindly suggest

I do not have any code yet. I have simple code where I am getting value for Roll no, from Database table using

**CLASS ACTIVITY CODE:**

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Spinner RollNumber;
    EditText Name;
    EditText Class;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_stock_move );


        myDb = new DatabaseHelper( this );
        LotNo1 = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.SpinnerDropDownSelectRollNo1ModifyScreen );
        Name = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.EditTextName );
        Class = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.EditTextClass );
        FetchRollNumber();

    }
//GEt RollNumber From Table_Class

    private void loadSpinnerRollNumber() {
        // database handler
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> lables = db.AvailableLot();


        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        RollNumber.setAdapter(dataAdapter);}

  //Code for Name

  //Code for Class

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

**DATABASE HELPER CODE:**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String Database_Name = "Class";
    public static final int Database_Version = 1;";
    public static final String Table_class = "ClassName";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "RollNo";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Name";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Class";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super( context, Database_Name, null, 1 );
    }

    @Override    
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL( "create table " + Table_class+ "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 0,ENTRYDATE TEXT,RollNo TEXT,Name TEXT,Class TEXT)" );

    }

        @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_class);

    }

// Update inventory table on stock add

 public List<String> AvailableLot() {

        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Table_class;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(3));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }

}
```

Comment: please share the code what you have done and tell us where you are facing the issue.

Comment: You need to read [Spinners](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner) and particularly about **OnItemSelectedListener**

Answer (score 0):

call following method from your SQLiteHandlerHelper in spinner setOnItemSelectedListener()

```
rollNumSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position != -1) {

                 String jsonResp = db.testData( rollNumArr[position]);                    
                // get this json response and extract name & address then set to respective edittext 
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {            
        }
    });
```

then in SQLiteHandlerHelper  add method

```
public String testData(String rollNum) {

    String res;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM tablename where rollNumColumnName = '" +rollNum+ "' ";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
            String address = cursor.getString(addressColumnIndex);

            res = "{\"isAvail\":true, \"name\":"+name+", \"address\":"+address+"}";

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } else {
        res = "{\"isAvail\":false}";
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return res;
}
```